# FQL Query Returning Inconsistent Results

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

I have the following FQL queries:

```
var comment_query  = "SELECT link_id, owner, owner_comment, title, summary, url, created_time FROM link WHERE owner=me() AND url='"+url+"'",
    like_query     = 'SELECT uid, page_id, type FROM page_fan WHERE uid = me() AND page_id='+pageId,
    likes          = FB.Data.query(like_query),
    comments       = FB.Data.query(comment_query);
FB.Data.waitOn([likes,comments],function(result) {
  ...
});
```

The result is intermittently empty on some browsers and computers.

As a preliminary test, I had two computers in the same room. Both using the same Facebook account, both running Windows 7, both on the latest version of Firefox, both starting Firefox in safe mode, both have their caches cleared.

One computer returns results, the other is consistently empty.

The only thing that I've found that will trigger a return result (if the browser is returning an empty result) is to put the page into the [Facebook debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).

Comment: Not sure what to tell you other than, are you sure both computers are pulling the same url and pageid?

Comment: Have you checked that the access tokens you are getting on the two computers match? Are you maybe requesting a new token when connecting to the application? If they don't match try using the debugger to check which one is valid.

Comment: Haven't tried checking that the access tokens are the same, that's probably a good start - thanks. I should also add that throwing things in the debugger doesn't consistently help, so it's probably just a fluke attribution.

Answer (score 0):

Is it always the same computer not receiving the data? Doesn't Firefox safe mode affect the accessibility of the results in some way? By any chance, isn't there some lock for the back to back retrieval of data from the same account? For example having same FB account logged in and ACTIVE might get treated as an illegal robot for data retrieval? Just throwing out ideas. What happens when you try to access the page with different Facebook accounts? If it is normal for both, then it means FB blocks frequent change of the source you are accessing the page with one account. Otherwise it means that something is wrong with browser one computer.

Answer (score 0):

Never did find out the exact cause.

Access tokens were valid.

No firm link between accounts or permissions. Inconsistent results between browsers/computers - for some it would always work, for others it never would. For some it started working, then failed at a later date.

Finally decided to skip the query and just [open a dialog directly](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/).